# Validation Pattern in Java and android?

Tags: java, android

Am validate First name in registration form,its allow only alphabets both lower case and upper case and (,/,#,-).

```
my validation patter is ^(([a-zA-Z])(/,#,-))*$
```

But its not validate correctly.Please any one help me to solve this problem and give a tips to create the pattern correctly.

Comment: Can you make an example which case it not working correctly?

Comment: Does "AsdF-" match? Does "As-Df"? Can it be empty? Can it have spaces? Some first names are made out of 2 or more names) You should define when it should work and when it shouldn't. Otherwise, it may take us a lot more time to help you. By the way, for a first name, are # and / actually used? I'm just confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean test = "a#aa-/".matches("^[a-zA-Z#/-]+$");
Log.e("TEst", "test " + test);
```

try this way

Answer (score 2):

Try out this regex: [a-zA-Z]+(\-[a-zA-Z]+)?

You can test regex online on vary websites like [this one](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

As sandkasten says you should provide examples of what's not working. I think you're looking for this

```
^([a-zA-Z]|[/#-])*$
```

The pipe (|) means character or one of those /#*

Answer (score 1):

Based on your premises (using /-#, not using spaces, but being a first name), it could be something like:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*([\/#\-][A-Z][a-z]*)*)$
```

This would match:

- Alfred
- Robert-Louis
- John#Joseph
- Kevin/Betty

But wouldn't

- CharLes (L is uppercase and shouln't)
- Mona- Sue (space)
- penny (P is not uppercase)

However, you definitely need to give us some examples, or we're just playing and not helping you. We don't have a crystal ball (at least me)